# Evaluate $\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I feel like I'm very close, so I would only like a hint. I'm only using real methods with the main thing I'm trying to connect the integral to is the Beta function. With a bunch of substitutions, I have boiled the integral down to

$$\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}dx=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2x^2(x^4-x^2+2)}{(1+x^2)^3\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$$
I feel like there is some substitution that could convert the integral into something in terms of the Beta function but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

For reference,
$$\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}dx=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(4\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right) $$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in going from the original integral ($0$ to $\pi/2$) to the next one ($0$ to $\infty$). The first one evaluates to $~1.826$; the second one evaluates to $1.910$.

Comment: My bad, it should be $\sin^2(x)$ thanks!

Comment: This is a complete elliptic integral of the second kind $$E(k) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-k\sin^2(x)}$$ The argument in this case is $k = -1$.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Although, I can't see how the integral simplifies into a representation in terms of the Gamma function (which is equivalent).

Comment: A side note. One may observe that $\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}>1$ giving $\int_{0}^M \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\,dx>\int_{0}^M 1\,dx$ then $\int_{0}^\infty \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\,dx$ **can't** be convergent.

Comment: Yep I’m aware this is related to the Elliptic Integral. I found this integral originally in Jack D’Aurizio’s notes under the Elliptic integrals section. He evaluated two integrals before this question using the Beta function and remarked that this integral could also be done like that.

Comment: And I made another boo-boo thanks for pointing that @OlivierOloa The upper bounce should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint 1:

> $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$$

Hint 2:

> Conjugate the "numerator" so that the only radical is in the denominator.

Hint 3:

> Perform a simple substitution so that you get a linear function inside the radical.

All steps shown:

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}~\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}}\cos(x)~\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}~\mathrm dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}~\mathrm dx=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{x^{-3/4}+x^{-1/4}}{\sqrt{1-x}}~\mathrm dx=\frac14B\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)+\frac14B\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the hints and the solution! Made much more sense afterwards.